About HttpClient and Class Method
I'm still at the beginning level, and my question may be a little naive.
Both HttpClient and directly calling class methods can request data from the server, so why use HttpClient instead of class methods?
e.g.
backend:
public Class DataService
{
    private readonly DataContext _db;
    
    public DataService(DataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    
    public async Task<List<Datas>> GetDatasAsync()
    {
        return await _db.Datas.ToListAsync();
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Datas>>> GetDatasHttpAsync()
    {
        return await _db.Datas.ToListAsync();
    }
}

fontend:
HttpClient:
httpDatas = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsyncList<Datas>(NavigationManager.BaseUri + "datas");

Class Method:
[inject DataService ds]
datas = await ds.GetDatasAsync();

In the front-end code block, both methods can get back data, why use the httpclien method instead of the class method
I searched for a long time, did not find the answer, ask seniors for advice

HttpClient is used in WASM to call the backend API. If your front-end web app doesn't host your API as well, you also need to use HttpClient to call the web app. When you want to build an agnostic component you inject a service whose implementation either calls the database or remote service

In .NET 8, if you want to use different render modes for different pages, or use automatic render mode, you can't assume that the component will run locally, so you can't assume DataContext will be available. In a services architecture, even with Blazor Server your frontend will call multiple independent services so once again you can't depend on a DataContext

Since you say that you're a beginner, I'd like to point you to the YAGNI principle. In this case, it means that you add a HttpClient->WebAPI layer only if know that you need it and not just because people say that it could be useful in certain scenarios. That having been said, separating the UI and the business logic/DB layer in your code makes sense in any case, and it also makes adding such an API layer later, when you actually need it, much easier.

I need to check that I understand your question correctly. I think you are asking, "With Blazor Server, why use a HttpClient and a Web API to get data from the backend, when I can just interact with the database directly from the frontend?"
It's quite ok to use either method with Blazor Server. The reason that it might be useful to use HttpClient to call a backend API is so that you could switch to Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) in the future very easily.
Blazor Server runs on the server, and parts of the UI are synchronised between the client and the server. You can picture it more like an MVC application with a JS managing the dynamic interactions. Therefore it's safe to make database calls from a page or component, because this code lives on the server.
Blazor WebAssembly runs in the client's browser, and therefore they could not make direct calls to your database like Blazor Server can, because the code is executed from the client's browser. It should not be able to reach your database.
So by splitting database work into backend services and then calling them via a HttpClient, it makes that part of the application compatible with Blazor Server Blazor WebAssembly.
You can read more about Blazor's hosting models here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-8.0
